# Did the U.S. sign any deal to put guardrails around the use and development of AI for military use according to what's available in the public domain?

Tags: united-states, military, international

> When US president Joe Biden meets with his Chinese counterpart Xi
> Jinping in the San Francisco Bay Area this week, the pair will have a
> long list of matters to discuss, including the Israel-Hamas war and
> Russia’s ongoing invasion of Ukraine.
>
> Behind the scenes at the APEC summit, however, US officials hope to
> strike up a dialog with China about placing guardrails around military
> use of artificial intelligence, with the ultimate goal of lessening
> the potential risks that rapid adoption—and reckless use—of the
> technology might bring.
>
> “We have a collective interest in reducing the potential risks from
> the deployment of unreliable AI applications” because of risks of
> unintended escalation, says a senior State Department official
> familiar with recent efforts to broach the issue and who spoke on
> condition of anonymity. “We very much hope to have a further
> conversation with China on this issue.”

https://www.wired.com/story/us-china-killer-ai-weapons-apec-talks/

Did the U.S. sign any deal to put guardrails around the use and development of AI for military use according to what's available in the public domain? The article describes that some U.S. officials want to sign an agreement with China to prevent an AI arms race. I am wondering if it signed any such deal or agreement, especially with countries that are allied with the United States like Germany and France.

Comment: TBH It's hard to say what is AI and what isn't. E.g. Patriot system has a mode that auto-shoot at targets etc.